# Where to find vma->fault()?

Tags: linux-kernel, memory

I understand `vma->fault()` will take two arguments which are `vma` and `vmf`. But I am not sure what `vma->fault()` will do inside of itself because I cannot find the code or document that talks about the initialization of this field in `vm_area_struct->vm_ops->fault()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for implementation `vma->fault()`, which is being executed in `mm/memory.c` in [__do_fault()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/memory.c#L2642) function:

```
ret = vma->vm_ops->fault(vma, &vmf);
```

### TL;DR

Short answer: [special_mapping_fault()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/mmap.c#L3011) function set up as `.fault` callback.

### Long story

When trying to find thing like this, one shouldn't underestimate power of simple Unix tools, like `grep`. Knowing that `.fault` callback belongs to memory management, we know that we should look into `mm/` directory. So here is the answer:

```
$ grep -sIrHn '\.fault = ' mm/*
```

And the output is next:

```
mm/hugetlb.c:2594:  .fault = hugetlb_vm_op_fault,
mm/mmap.c:3001:     .fault = special_mapping_fault,
mm/mmap.c:3007:     .fault = special_mapping_fault,
```

Investigating further we can figure out that `mm/hugetlb.c` is part of HugeTLB FS implemetation, hence has nothing to do with your case.

For both other cases you can see that `special_mapping_fault()` function is using as `.fault` callback.